# Displaying a UIViewController view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, storyboard

I'm displaying a `UIViewController` as one of the pages in a `UIPageViewController`.

This viewController (VC1) has a size of (320, 568). What I then do is display another VC using this method:

```
- (void)displayContentController:(UIViewController *)content {
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Called this way:

```
NewViewController *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
[self displayContentController:newVC];
```

The reason I'm doing this instead of pushing it or presenting it modally, is because I need it to overlap the other `UIViewController`(VC1), blurring it while sliding with the `UIPageViewController` like VC1 normally would.

`viewDidLoad` in `newVC` is reporting a `self.view.frame` of (320, 568) at first, but then a little later it suddenly reports a `self.view.frame` of (320, 571) - rather than a height of 568.

**I'm using autolayout.**

Why is this and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad()` method frames don't give you actual size of controller views. To get correct sizes try to check it in `viewdidlayoutsubviews()` method of ViewController

Comment: I see. But I have a problem whereas I have a tableView that's constrained to the bottom layout guide in `newVC`, but increasing that constraint's constant value equivalent to the height of the keyboard when displayed, still makes the table appear just a little bit underneath the keyboard which makes me think `newVC` is too tall. That the bottom of the VC is under the actual screen bottom